# Footnote marker for the image inside the footnote is placed at the bottom

Tags: graphics, footnotes

I place an image inside the footnote like this:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{extbook}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Light Table\footnote{an integrated development environment, first appeared in 12 April 2012} was developed with the aim of showing the effects of adding code in real-time, rather than requiring one to work out the effects after the code is written.

Here is a sceenshot\footnotemark\footnotetext{
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image-a}} 
\end{document}
```

but the footnote marker for the image is placed at the bottom.

[image]

I'd like to place the marker on top, as it's shown in the screenshot.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will correct the issue by lowering the figure to the level of the footnotemark.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{extbook}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    
\begin{document}    

    Light Table\footnote{an integrated development environment, first appeared in 12 April 2012} was developed with the aim of showing the effects of adding code in real-time, rather than requiring one to work out the effects after the code is written.
    
    Here is a screenshot\footnotemark.
    
    \footnotetext{%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+0.4\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image-a}}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: You  can also use valign with `\includegrpahics` if you also  add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`.